# Is there a Rule based data merging or combining library for .net?

Tags: .net, merge

I am looking for any available libraries or tools that can be used to build a rule based data merging application. e.g. an example of what I am trying to achieve:

Scenario : I receive similar data from 2 providers ProviderA and ProviderB for Stock Listed Companies

```
Provider A:
Name : Nokia Oy
Ticker : NOK1V
Country of Issue : Finland
Risk Country : Finland

Provider B:
Name : Nokia Oy
Ticker : NOK1V
Country of Issue : Finland
Risk Country : USA
```

I want to merge the data from provider A and provider B using a rule that says

```
When Ticker = NOK1V then use Provider B except for RiskCountry -> Use Provider A
```

This needs to be user configurable so ETL tools like SSIS are not what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296598/net-rules-engines

Comment: Many thanks for the link. I'm aware of a few generic Business Rule Engines. I am holding out hope that something exists that is specifically designed for data merge / combine operations , but of course any decent generic BRE or even a DSL could be used for this -it might require a bit more work on my part and I don't want to re-invent the wheel if something good already exists.